# Proving that set is a hyperspace by definition

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, differential-geometry

While reading a necessary condition for an extremum with constraint from Zorich's book (volume I, page 528) I asked myself the following question:

**Question.** Let $D$ be an open subset in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $f:D\to \mathbb{R}$ such that $f\in C^1(D;\mathbb{R})$. Assume that $x_0\in D$ and $\nabla f(x_0)\neq\vec{0}$. Consider $N:=\{x\in D: f(x)=f(x_0)\}$. How to prove that $N$ is an $(n-1)$-dimensional submanifold of $\mathbb{R}^n$?

Zorich gives the following definition of a $k$-dimensional submanifold of $\mathbb{R}^n$.

> **Definition 1.** We shall call a set $S\subset \mathbb{R}^n$ a $k$-dimensional smooth surface in $\mathbb{R}^n$ (or a $k$-dimensional
> submanifold of $\mathbb{R}^n$) if for every point $x_0\in S$ there
> exist a neighborhood $U(x_0)$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and a diffeomorphism
> $\varphi:U(x_0)\to I^n$ of this neighborhood onto the standard
> $n$-dimensional cube $I^n=\{t\in \mathbb{R}^n: |t^i|<1,\  i=1,\dots,n\}$
> of the space $\mathbb{R}^n$ under which the image of the set $S\cap
>  U(x_0)$ is the portion of the $k$-dimensional plane in $\mathbb{R}^n$
> defined by the relations $t^{k+1}=0,\dots, t^n=0$ lying inside $I^n$.

**EDIT 1:** I can answer my question if we assume $\nabla f(x)\neq \vec{0}$ for all $x\in D$. I will show that $N$ is a $(n-1)$-dimensional submanifold of $\mathbb{R}^n$. Indeed, let $a=(a_1,\dots,a_n)\in N$ then we know that $\nabla f(a)\neq \vec{0}$. WLOG, assume that $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x^1}(a)\neq 0$. Consider the mapping $\Phi:D\to \mathbb{R}^n$ defined as $\vec{x}\mapsto(f(x)-f(x_0),x^2,\dots,x^n)$, where $x=(x^1,\dots,x^n)$. It is not difficult to see that $\Phi\in C^1(D;\mathbb{R}^n)$ and $\det J_{\Phi}(a)\neq 0$, where $J_{\Phi}(a)$ is a Jacobian of our mapping at $a$. By inverse function theorem there exist $O_1=O_1(a)$ neighborhood of $a$ and $O_2=O_2(\Phi(a))$ neighborhood of $\Phi(a)$ such that $\Phi:O_1\to O_2$ is a diffeomorphism. We notice that $\Phi(a)=(0,a_2,\dots,a_n)$ and we can find a cube around $\Phi(a)$ which is contained in $O_2$ and assume that $$Q=(-r,r)\times \prod_{j=2}^n (a_j-r,a_j+r).$$
Let $P:=\Phi^{-1}(Q)$, then $P\subset O_1$ and $P$ is a neighborhood of $a$ (because $\Phi$ is a diffeomorphism). Therefore, for $a\in N$ we were able to find its neghborhood $P=P(a)$ and diffeomorphism $\Phi$ such that $\Phi:P(a)\to Q$. Moreover, it is not difficult to check that $$\Phi(P(a)\cap N)=\{0\}\times \prod_{j=2}^n (a_j-r,a_j+r).$$ By definition 1, it follows that $N$ is a $(n-1)$-dimensional submanifold.

**Remark.** But in the original question we assumed that $\nabla f(x_0)\neq 0$. WLOG suppose that $\partial_1 f(x_0)\neq 0$ Since $f\in C^1(D;\mathbb{R})$, then there exists $O(x_0)\subset D$, where $O(x_0)$ is a neighborhood of $x_0$ such that $\partial_1f(x)\neq 0$ for all $x\in O(x_0)$. It implies that $\nabla f(x)\neq \vec{0}$ for all $x\in O(a)$. Using previous reasoning it implies that $\tilde{N}:=\{x\in O(x_0): f(x)=f(x_0)\}$ is a $(n-1)$-dimensional submanifold. But it does not imply that $N$ is a $(n-1)$-dimensional submanifold.

I hope now my question is posed correctly and it maked sense what am I asking.
Thank you!

**EDIT 2:** I created this post because Zorich proves the following result in his book:

> **Theorem 1.** Let $f:D\to \mathbb{R}$ be a function defined on an open set $D\subset \mathbb{R}^n$ and belonging to $C^1(D;\mathbb{R})$.
> Let $S$ be a smooth surface in $D$.  A necessary condition for a point
> $x_0\in S$ that is noncritical for $f$ to be a  local extremum of
> $\left.f\right|_S$ is that $$TS_{x_0}\subset TN_{x_0},$$ where
> $TS_{x_0}$ is the tangent space to the surface $S$ at $x_0$ and
> $TN_{x_0}$ is the  tangent space to the level surface $N = \{x \in D: f(x) = f(x_0)\}$ of $f$ to which  $x_0$ belongs.

So my concern was that one cannot define surface $N$ in the way he did. I mean $N$ should be defined as $\{x\in O(x_0): f(x)=f(x_0)\}$, where $O(x_0)\subset D$ is a neighborhood of $x_0$, where $\nabla f(x)\neq 0$. Is that correct?

Comment: With your reputation you should know that is not how this works.

Comment: You should show some effort towards solving that problem. Also, this result's proof (or similar) can be found in standard texts.

Comment: @JohnDouma, sorry but what do you mean? I think asking math question has nothing with a reputation.

Comment: You are asking us to provide you with a rigorous proof without showing any effort. You should know the guidelines for a good question by now.

Comment: @JohnDouma, sorry about that! I edited my answer now. Please take a look. I hope now it makes sense what I am asking.

Comment: @RollenS.D'Souza, I edited my post! Hopefully, now it makes more sense and looks good. Hopefully you can remove your downvote.

Comment: looks good to me

Comment: @RollenS.D'Souza, excuse but what do you mean?

Comment: i was merely commenting the post meets standards now.

Comment: @ZFR It does. Thank you.

Comment: @JohnDouma thank you very much! can you take a look at edit 2 which I've added few minutes ago? I just want to be sure that my understanding is correct.

Comment: But isn't $D$ already open? Why do we have to restrict that further? We are only interested in the gradient at $x_0$ which should be the same for all open sets containing $x_0$.

Comment: @JohnDouma, yeah $D$ is open but we don't know that $\nabla f(x)\neq 0$ for all $x\in D$. Actually this guarantees that $N$ is a submanifold. Does it make sense now?

Comment: Why does the gradient have to be non-zero for all $x$? It seems like Theorem $1$ is talking about a single point. Am I missing something?

Comment: @JohnDouma, if the gradient is nonzero at some $x_0$, then $N$ may not be manifold (see the example provided by @aschepler). If $\nabla f(x)\neq 0$ for all $x\in D$, then $N$ is a $(n-1)$-dimensional submanifold (I wrote the proof in EDIT 1).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right, in general $N$ is not an $(n-1)$-dimensional submanifold of $\mathbb R^n$. Zorich himself says it in his book.

In Proposition 2 on p.486 he proves a *local result* as you expect. In Example 2 on p.487 he explicitly states

> Thus, in a neighborhood of a noncritical point $x_0$ of $F$ the equation
> $$F(x^1,\ldots,x^m) = 0$$
> defines an $(m — l)$-dimensional surface.

Unfortunately he is a bit sloppy in the sequel. On p.488 he writes

> It can be seen from these equations that, given the Euclidean structure
> on $\mathbb R^m$, one can assert that the vector
> $$\operatorname{grad} F(x_0) = \left(\frac{\partial F}{\partial x^1},\ldots,\frac{\partial F}{\partial x^m} \right)(x_0 )$$
> is orthogonal to the $r$-level surface $F(x) = r$ of the function $F$ at a corresponding point $x_0 \in \mathbb R^m$.

He should have said something like "local $r$-level surface $F(x) = r$".

The same sloppyness oocurs in Theorem 1 on p.528. This theorem gives a necessary condition for a point $x_0 \in S$ to be a **local** extremum of $f \mid_S$. It it is clear that it is irrelevant here what $N$ looks globally, it suffices to know that it locally a submanifold around $x_0$.

To prove that $N$ is a submanifold *globally* we must require that $y_0 = f(x_0)$ is a *regular value* of $f$  which means that all $\xi \in f^{-1}(y_0)$ are non-critical points (aka *regular points*).

Comment: Thank you very much! Very useful answer!

Comment: @ZFR Not at the moment, I am travelling for the next two weeks.

Comment: Sure! No worries!

Comment: I'll leave a link here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4720767/question-about-notation-fx-ogx-over-the-base-mathcalb

Answer (score 2):

The only technical issue with the Theorem 1 you quote is that the definition of $N$ is over all of $D$. As another answerer has pointed out, this is false in general. However, Theorem 1 is a local criterion (whether or not a point is an extremum) and so really the set $D$ can be restricted (without loss of generality) to a sufficiently small open set containing $x_0$ so that $\nabla f$ is non-zero on $D$ and so $N$ is sufficiently well-defined. Indeed if $f$ is $C^1$ and $\nabla f(x_0)$ is non-zero then there exists a restriction of the open set $D$ containing $x_0$ where $\nabla f$ is non-zero everywhere and a further restriction (if required) to keep $N$ well-defined. Said differently, once $\nabla f(x_0)\neq 0$ is known then we can shrink $D$ without loss of generality to make $N$ well-defined thereby making the necessary condition testable.

It would be overly pedantic (in my opinion) to consider a smaller neighbourhood of $D$ since the theorem is a necessary condition anyway. Being unable to construct $N$ on some set $D$ does not mean no restriction of $D$ exists where you can construct it --- assuming that $x_0$ is a non-critical point of course.

Comment: Thank you! In my opinion I guess it is not pedantic. So it turns out that I was right when I said in the definition of $N$ one should take a small neighborhood of $x_0$ which lies in $D$ in order to get a submanifold $N$.

Comment: @ZFR Indeed, it is a completely local construction.

Answer (score 1):

Just knowing $\nabla f(x_0) \neq 0$ does not mean $N$ must be a 1-manifold. That doesn't tell us enough about behavior of $f$ far from $x_0$. In particular, $f$ could have $\nabla f = 0$ everywhere in some other open set.

For example, take $f: (0,5) \times (-1,1)$ as

$$ f(x,y) = \begin{cases} 0 & 0 < x < 2 \\ 2-x & 2 \leq x < 3 \\ x-4 & 3 \leq x < 5 \end{cases} $$

(Oops, $f$ isn't $C^1$, but a similar function from joining quadratic pieces instead of linear would work for that.)

$f$ is continuous. At the point $x_0 = (4,0)$, $f(x_0)=0$ and $\nabla f(x_0) = (1,0)$. But $N = f^{-1}(\{0\}) = ((0,2] \cup \{4\}) \times (-1,1)$ which cannot be a 1-manifold, since it contains $(0,2) \times (-1,-1)$, an open set of $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Comment: Sorry but which proposition exactly do you mean?

Comment: I did not read your example yet but I will do it! So where is the mistake in my reasoning? We know that $\nabla f(x_0)\neq \vec{0} \Leftrightarrow (\partial_1 f(x_0),\dots,\partial_n f(x_0))\neq (0,\dots,0)$. WLOG, assume that $\partial_1 f(x_0)\neq 0$. We know that $f\in C^1(D;\mathbb{R})$ which is the same as partial derivatives are continuous on $D$.

Comment: In particular, $\partial_1 f\in C(D;\mathbb{R})$ and since $\partial_1f(x_0)\neq 0$, then $\exists O(x_0)\subset D$ such that for all $x\in O(x_0)$ we have $\partial_1 f(x)\neq 0$. Therefore, for each $x\in O(x_0)$ we have $\nabla f(x)=(\partial_1f(x),\dots,\partial_nf(x))\neq \vec{0}$. I do not see any mistake. I believe that each step is true. Moreover, all the details which I've provided are rigorous enough.

Comment: The question assumes $f$ is continuously differentiable once

Comment: I think in your example $N=f^{-1}(\{0\})$ should be equal to $((0,2]\cup \{4\})\times (-1,1)$.

Comment: @ZFR Sorry, I clarified. Your proof when $\nabla f \neq 0$ everywhere is valid. I answered the case when we just know $\nabla f(x_0) \neq 0$, which I thought was the main question.

Comment: @RollenS.D'Souza Aha, true. We could still build that sort of function by splicing quadratics, or even a smooth $f$ using the usual half of $e^{-1/x}$.

Comment: Oh yeah! Now it makes sense! I am wondering could you take a look at EDIT 2 which I've added a while ago? That was the motivation why I asked this question. Just want to be sure that I have a correct understanding.

Comment: Agreed! Just best to keep the example in scope